# Synchronising local and remote DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization

I have a general question about DB synchronisation.

So, I'm developing a website locally (PHP + MySQL) and I would like to be able to synchronise at least the structure (and maybe the contents) of the two DB when one of the two is changed (normally I would change the local copy).

Right now what I'm doing is to use `mysqldump` to dump the modified tables and then import them in the remote DB or do it by hand if the changes are minimal. However I find this tedious and error-prone.

For the PHP I'm currently using Quanta+ which has the handy feature of finding files that have changed and just upload those. Is there something similar for MySQL?

Otherwise how do you keep your DBs synchronised?

Thanks
nico

PS: I'm sorry if this was already asked, I saw other questions that deal with similar topics, but couldn't really find an answer.

Comment: @Will: can I please ask why this was closed? I would not say it is OT... maybe it does not immediately look like a programming question, but it was meant to find a way to automatize the insertion of data in a DB.

Comment: Well, its not really programming related.  Also, its attracting spam, which is why I wandered in here.  A question like this should belong on [dba.se] now, although they would likely discourage its descent into product endorsement theater.  No bad on your part, so please don't take it personally.

Comment: @Will: no offense taken. The question is answered, anyway, so no need to migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:
[MySQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/MySQL_Compare/index.htm)

Comment: That looks more like what I'm looking for. Too bad it's just for Windows, but I guess I can run it under Wine or in a VM.

Comment: I also found another similar project (I think, haven't really tried it yet) that runs on Linux, sqlyog http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continuously keep your DB instances synced - you should use a proper **master-slave** configuration as your DB landscape.

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html for more info on replication.

If replication is not available, you can use the binary logs (which record all operationso n the database) on one machine and run them on the second machine whenever you want to sync the instances.

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html

Again, you might be needing access to certain configuration files. If this option is irrelevant, then you might need to fall back to other methods which are much less reliable.

Comment: I don't need them to be continuously synced. A tool that allows to sync them every once in a while would be fine. Replication would be a good idea, but I fear I cannot use it as the remote server is shared and I do not have access to configuration files.